Quantity of Products in Segmentation in Salesforce CPQ
I have a question about how quantity works when it comes to fully segmented products. In a normal scenario, when there is no change in the product quantity during configuration, the product quantity is set to zero when the subscriptions are generated. In this case, since I didn't make any changes to any line, I can use the segmentation quantity field to have a total value (even though I don't really understand why the quantity in the subscription is zero).
However, in specific cases, such as when I have to configure a Ramp up, the segment quantities start to behave in a way that the quantity of subsequent subscriptions reflects the difference from the previous one, as described in this article (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390779&type=1).
The question is: if my client does not want this behavior and wants the quantity entered in the segmentation configuration to be the quantity generated in the subscription, is there a way to disable it natively? How can I work around this if it's not possible? One solution could be a trigger at the time of generating the subscription, forcing the value configured in the OrderItem quantity field?
